# AJAX GET keep opening old version of file

Tags: jquery, ajax, file, get

I have a dashboard that manages several files that is managed by other people.

What it does is it will display its content using AJAX Get every 2.5 seconds to see if there are new content.

But for some reason, even after the file is updated, it still displays the same content.

Below is my code:

```
window.setInterval(function(){runscript();}, 2500);
    function runscript(){

        var name = $("#filesname").val().split(';');
        for (var n = 0; n < name.length -1; n++)
        {
            var check = false;
            var tmpname = name[n].split('.');
            var request = jQuery.get('./tmp/'+name[n], function(data) {
                // Process the file
                    });
                }
            });
            request.success(function(result) {
              console.log(result);
            });

            request.error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              if (textStatus == 'timeout')
                alert('The server is not responding');

              if (textStatus == 'error'){
                  if(errorThrown == "Not Found")
                  {
                  }
              }
              // Etc
            });
        }
    }
```

I tried to alert the page content and it does loop every 2.5 seconds, but it displays the old content even after updated. Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, apparently it's because of the cache. I need to append 'nocache' to the URL:

```
var request = jQuery.get('./tmp/'+name[n]+'?nocache=' + Date.now(), function(data) {
```